# Keycloak user Invitation email

Tags: python, django, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am using Keycloak-9.0.2 as SSO in my Django project. I want to get send an invitation link in the e-mail by one user to another user.
Is there any inbuilt functionality in Keycloak for the same? If not then what should be the better way to do this in Django.

Comment: I don't know about Keycloak, but sending emails with Django is easy! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#send-mail Beware though that you don't allow your users to spam other users without their consent.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [python-keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) library like this:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin

keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                           username='example-admin',
                           password='secret',
                           realm_name="master",
                           user_realm_name="only_if_other_realm_than_master",
                           client_secret_key="client-secret",
                           verify=True)
# Add user                       
new_user = keycloak_admin.create_user({"email": "example@example.com",
                "username": "example@example.com",
                "enabled": True,
                "requiredActions": ["UPDATE_PASSWORD", "UPDATE_PROFILE", "VERIFY_EMAIL"]})


# Get user ID from name
user_id_keycloak = keycloak_admin.get_user_id("example@example.com")

# Send User Action
response = keycloak_admin.send_update_account(user_id=user_id_keycloak, 
                                          payload=json.dumps(["UPDATE_PASSWORD", "UPDATE_PROFILE", "VERIFY_EMAIL"]))
```

Then you will get invite email like this:

[image: Email invite example]